# How to control when combobox result is null in switch-case

Tags: c#

I'm try to this : 1. click button -> 2. check combobox.selectedItem -> 3. do something

But if combobox not selected, switch-case is return null exception

I solved this with try-catch but i'm looking for way can switch-case is handling "null" result without try-catch

I thought default: can handle this but it can't

What do I do?

**This is e.g. of my code**

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(constr))
            {
                try
                {
                    switch (comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString())
                    {
                        case "something1":
                            textBox1.Text = "111";
                            break;
                        case "something2":
                            textBox1.Text = "111";
                            break;
                        case "something3":
                            textBox1.Text = "111";
                            break;
                        default:
                            MessageBox.Show("select combobox!");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                catch ( Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("select combobox!!");
                } 
    }
}
```

Comment: use `if(comboBox.SelectedItem == null) {MessageBox.Show("select combobox!!");}` before `using (OledbConnection...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought default: can handle this but it can't

It can, but you still have to make sure that a valid expression is evaluated for the `switch` statement.

Which you can do, using the `?.` (null conditional) operator:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(constr))
{
    switch (comboBox.SelectedItem?.ToString())
    {
        case "something1":
            textBox1.Text = "111";
            break;
        case "something2":
            textBox1.Text = "111";
            break;
        case "something3":
            textBox1.Text = "111";
            break;
        default:
            MessageBox.Show("select combobox!");
            break;
    }
}
```

If `SelectedItem` is null, then the entire expression will "short-circuit", i.e. not go on to try to evaluated the `ToString()` method call. Instead, the value of the expression will be `null`. Since `null` doesn't match any of the explicit `case` statements, the `default` case will be executed.

There are a variety of other ways you could deal with the potentially-null value, but given your original code and your interest in using the `default` case to do it, this would be the most straight-forward approach.